# Change Front End, by one particularly

Tags: front-end

As I get visual interface for mathematica [front end], I always appear so, writing

[image: example]

Edit>|Image not take or ellipse or code, as I give this style of presentation to mathematica for any notebook to write, I mean whenever you run Mathematica also display its interface

Edit 2 : I need to format the front -  end to have that particular style that shows the image with colors, but this default.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: I think there may be a language barrier here.  I suggest including the question in your native language with the hope that someone will translate for you.

Comment: Please include the actual code you are using, rather than an image of the code and its output..  Doing so will produce more effective responses.

Comment: You can use `SetOptions` to change option presets,  either directly in a given notebook  or globally  via `init.m`.

Comment: ** Yves Klett , hello, you can put a code sample, please

Comment: You don't have to make a separate parametric plot to get a read edge on your yellow ellipse. You can add the edge with `EdgeForm[Red],` In your case `Graphics[{Yellow, EdgeForm[Red], Rotate[Disk[{xc, yc}, {Abs[a], b}], phi]}] /. ...` should work

Comment: I do not care Ellipse, just write format, ie each notebook that do have that color format. Fernando